# How can I select a cell range from a particular cell to last cell in VS Code Jupyter notebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I apologize if this is a basic question, but suppose I want to select cells from cell 9 to last cell in VS Code Jupyter notebook. What is the keyboard shortcut to do this?

I tried selecting the cell 9 and then using the command shift+end ,but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about keyboard-only shortcuts, but you can use the mouse with conventional keyboard shortcuts. You just need to click in the space under a cell (below its input and output elements, and before the input of the following cell). Ex. ctrl (or cmd on macOS) + click on the space under a cell will add/remove (it's a toggle) that cell to the selection of cell. Using shift instead will select between the last-clicked cell and the newly-clicked cell.

So for example, to select from cell 9 to the last cell, put the cursor/caret in cell 9's input box, then scroll down to the last cell, hold <kbd>shift</kbd>, and click the space just under the last cell.